# Python - group by + transform + substring

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to extract values from a string in a pandas data frame using other two columns as indices.

My data looks like this.

```
  Address          second_dot  third_dot  
0  1.273.1735.0           5         10  
1    1.263.48.0           5          8  
2  1.273.1341.0           5         10  
3  1.273.1527.0           5         10  
4  1.273.1379.0           5         10  
5  1.273.1094.0           5         10  
6   1.273.845.0           5          9  
7  1.273.1393.0           5         10  
8   1.275.988.0           5          9  
9   1.273.973.0           5          9
```

In columns second_dot and third_dot I've stored the position of within column 'address' of the '.' characters. What I would like to do is to extract from each rows all characters between second and third dot.

The result should be like this:

```
 Result
    273
    263
    273
    273
    273
    273
    273
    273
    275
    273
```

I've already managed to do it by using apply on axis 1 with custom function, but it takes too long (I've got millions or records in my data frame. Considering that the address are repeated over lines, I'm trying to group by the calculation, hoping to speed up.

This is my last attempt, but it does not work.

```
df.groupby(['Address']).transform(lambda x : 
x['Address'].str[x['first_dot']:x['second_dot']])
```

I get error --> `KeyError: ('Address', 'occurred at index MachineIdentifier').`

MachineIdentifier is the first column of my df (not the index, a normal column)

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: "extract from each rows all characters between second and third dot."...but "Result 273 263 273 273 273 273 273 273 275 273"  is between first and second dot?